# Is it possible to use a global AJAX listener to get the source of the AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/tsmknfr2/1/).

If I have the following code:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button id='firstButton'>
    first button
  </button>
  <button id='secondButton'>
    second button
  </button>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$("button").click(function(event) {
    var targetId = event.target.id;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://fiddle.jshell.net",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('target id is: ' + targetId);
    }
  });
});

// Is it possible for this to work the same as the above somehow?
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, data) {
  var targetId = event.target.id; // Event.target is `document` so does not work
  alert('target id is: ' + targetId); // I want this to be the same alert as above.
});
```

Is it possible to pass the id of the button firing an AJAX call to a global listener (`$(document).ajaxSuccess`)?

Comment: The "global" part of this question is probably a bad idea. If you ever brought in libraries later which used `$.ajax` it will mess with things.

Comment: @4castle I'm not sure - perhaps my question isn't clear? It sounds to me like you're saying the entire [jQuery library for global event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) should never have been written in the first place. I feel like jQuery is a large enough library for that question to have been weighed and answered appropriately. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm just concerned that adding an additional event handler for id checking to *all* ajax requests would be overkill for applications that make heavy use of ajax requests. Only a portion of ajax requests would have an associated DOM element with an id. To some extent it's a matter of preference. I'm the kind of person who likes to be explicit about what code runs when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, pass it along with the ajax options, then pull it from the ajax options.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsmknfr2/6

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  var targetId = event.target.id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://fiddle.jshell.net",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('target id is: ' + targetId);
    },
    foop: targetId
  });
});

// Is it possible for this to work the same as the above somehow?
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, data) {
  var targetId = ajaxOptions.foop; 
  alert('target id is: ' + targetId); 
});
```

Comment: True, i was a bit lazy. I didn't use the first line though at least.

Comment: I really like this solution - is this a bad practice or perfectly OK?

Comment: It's perfectly fine, as long as you don't use a property name that could be getting used by something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that opts-in to the binding beforehand. You can use this function every time you want to first run the alert before your callback. Include any fields you plan on accessing in your function in the `$.ajax` options.

This is better than having a global `$.ajax` catcher or modifying the `$.ajax` function itself because it doesn't pollute all of the ajax requests in the page which don't have an associated `id`.

```
function ajaxCallback(callback) {
  return function() {
    // "this" will be the object you passed to "$.ajax"
    alert("target id is: " + this.targetId);
    callback && callback.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

$("button").click(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    success: ajaxCallback(function(data, status, xhr) {
      // success handler here
    }),
    targetId: event.target.id
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phgz2vcz/3/)